# zxing Data matrix gets blurred when scaled

Tags: objective-c, zxing

Is there a way to get the datamatrix to not be blurred when scaled in a UIView, The width and height only makes the datamatrix more complex, I want like 16x16 dots but when I make it bigger its divided into 4 cells. The datamatrix scans really quick but the designers want it pixel perfect.

```
   ZXMultiFormatWriter *writer = [ZXMultiFormatWriter writer];
if (writer && self.myString.length) {

    ZXBitMatrix *result = [writer encode:self.myString
                                  format:kBarcodeFormatDataMatrix
                                   width:16
                                  height:16 error:&error];
    if (result) {
        ZXImage *zxImage = [ZXImage imageWithMatrix:result];

        if (zxImage) {
            CGImageRef cgImage = [zxImage cgimage];
            if (cgImage) {
                UIImage *barCodeImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
                if (barCodeImage) {
                    self.barcodeImageView.image = barCodeImage;
                    [self showDataMatrixHideBarcode];
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably adding:

```
[[self.barcodeImageView layer] setMagnificationFilter:kCAFilterNearest];
```

before you set the image on the imageView is what you want.

Don't forget to add:

```
#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>
```

to your file too!

Answer (score 0):

this is how we solved it

```
  self.dataMatrixImageView.layer.magnificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest;
  self.dataMatrixImageView.image = dataMatrixImage;
```